# How to uninstall something that was installed from Terminal, setting up ROR on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I am in the process of installing ruby on rails for new mac os 10.9. I had downloaded Xcode and then ran the command (with Homebrew installed)

```
brew install apple-gcc42
```

Which it seems (from what I've been reading) that you don't need this is you have Xcode and Xcode command line tools installed. Is this correct?

How do I uninstall this program (apple-gcc42) that was installed by the terminal?

Also what should be the path I take for setting up ROR on mac as I've previously come from developing on a Windows7 Machine and there seems to be a lot of differences.

Please guide me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay so I worked this out. Simply use the command:

```
brew uninstall apple-gcc42
```

Done.